# Css solution for dropping sidebar in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am building web located at www.kraken.ikas.sk
and I have problem with dropping right sidebar in IE7. I have 2 sidebars (width 180px) and in the middle is main_content that should resize according to the presence of the right sidebar. So it can not have fixed width.
Please find me some css solution (hack).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table` / `display: table-cell` for modern browsers, and [emulation polyfill](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/) for IE6-7 if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for a pure css solution with no emulators. (I do not optimize for IE6 anymore, so solution for IE7 should be enough).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using JS for obsolete browsers having small market share (IE7 has less than 1% market share according to [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201210-201212)).

Comment: First I want to use pure css solution (I believe it can be done). If really can not be done, I will use your solution.